# Reports showing Account Activities email field blank despite the fact that salesforce has value

Tags: apex, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I have created a custom report type - Account ( as primary object) and Activites as related object.

[image]

But when i am adding  coloum- email from activities, reports showing field blank in all records, despite all records has email field with value in activities in salesforce.. Please suggest. I am running as system Admin.

Comment: Does the user have access to the email field?

Comment: Are you using Person Account? I wonder if the Email field it's a custom field or not.
How did you add the Email field to your custom report type? Via lookup?

Comment: @SebastianKessel Yes user have access to that field.  Thanks

Comment: David, I'm not sure how you added the Email field to your report type, as Activities is "made up" of Tasks/Events. They both have an Email field. Is this Email field a custom one?

Comment: @Rodrigo, Thanks for quick reply.  we have added one custom field to activity called email too. We have encrypted too the new field due to security. I wonder is it due to encryption that new Custom field is not showing any value on that record. Thanks

Comment: By Default no profile can see Encrypted Data.

Only those profile which has “View Encrypted Data” permission can see encrypted fields and by default this permission is not given to any profile. You have to active this permission in profile by checking “View Encrypted Data” check box .

Comment: @thanks Rodrigo, I tried that but nothing happened. Still record has no values.